# Can't download files from global area codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have these structure in my codeigniter app:

```
application
|
 --- some other folders
|
system
|
 --- some other folders
|
global
|
 --- docs
     |
      --- target folder
          |
           --- MY FILE
```

Now, I want my users download a file from  `http://test.com/global/docs/targetfolder/MYFile`

**but** codeigniter behave with download address as `http:://test.com/controller/method/variable` and I'll get `404` error.

Would you please let me know how can I fix this situation?

***This is my main .htaccess file***

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
#RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]


<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Connection keep-alive 
 </ifModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: have you tried this? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html

Comment: yes, and it didn't help...

Comment: show your code what path you use in `force_download()`?